# how to add checkbox column to gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

How to add checkbox column to gridview .

i've tried:

```
foreach (GridViewRow objRow in GridView1.Rows)
{
   TableCell tcCheckCell = new TableCell();
   CheckBox chkCheckBox = new CheckBox();
   tcCheckCell.Controls.Add(chkCheckBox);

   objRow.Cells.Add( tcCheckCell);
}
```

How can i add the `objrow` to gridview? Or is there any other method of adding a checkbox column to an ASP.net `GridView`?

Comment: Is there something wrong with the code you posted?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov No checkbox appears.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you cannot add a *`CheckBox` field* to a `GridView` in order to have a column of checkboxes - the GridView doesn't support it:

Instead you have to change the ***template*** of each row, manually adding a *`CheckBox` control* to the template of a row.

- i can't tell you how to do that
- i can't tell you how to read which items the user has checked
- i can't tell you how to default some of them to checked

But it's what you have to do.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/adding-a-gridview-column-of-checkboxes-vb) is a good example of how to do it.