# c# Add Checkbox colum to GridViewColum WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to add a CheckboxColum to a Gridview, I am completely stuck. I does not work in WPf

```
var gridView = new GridView();

GridViewColumn col = new GridViewColumn();

col.Header = "Colum ";
col.Width = 100;
col.CellTemplate =  (DataTemplate) ......
col.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("BooleanData");
gridView.Columns.Add(col);
```

I'm stuck here

```
col.CellTemplate = (DataTemplate) CheckBox ....
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075044/how-to-add-checkbox-column-to-gridview

Answer (score 3):

You just need to change this line ...

```
GridViewColumn col = new GridViewColumn();
```

to this (WinForms)

```
CheckBoxColumn checkCol = new CheckBoxColumn();
```

or this (WPF)

```
CheckBoxColumn checkCol = new DataGridCheckBoxColumn();
```

Here is a list of all column types 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bxt3k60s.aspx

Comment: I tryed in WPF it does not exist in colum type

Comment: try DataGridCheckBoxColumn in WPF

Answer (score 1):

Create a class with the below given code:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections;
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for DynamicTemplate
/// </summary>
public class DynamicTemplate : System.Web.UI.ITemplate
{
public String TableName { get; set; }

System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItemType templateType;
System.Collections.Hashtable htControls = new System.Collections.Hashtable();
System.Collections.Hashtable htBindPropertiesNames = new System.Collections.Hashtable();
System.Collections.Hashtable htBindExpression = new System.Collections.Hashtable();

public DynamicTemplate(System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItemType type)
{
    templateType = type;
}

public void AddControl(WebControl wbControl, String BindPropertyName, String BindExpression)
{
    htControls.Add(htControls.Count, wbControl);
    htBindPropertiesNames.Add(htBindPropertiesNames.Count, BindPropertyName);
    htBindExpression.Add(htBindExpression.Count, BindExpression);
}

public void AddControl(HtmlControl wbControl, String BindPropertyName, String BindExpression)
{
    htControls.Add(htControls.Count, wbControl);
    htBindPropertiesNames.Add(htBindPropertiesNames.Count, BindPropertyName);
    htBindExpression.Add(htBindExpression.Count, BindExpression);
}

public void InstantiateIn(System.Web.UI.Control container)
{
    PlaceHolder ph = new PlaceHolder();

    for (int i = 0; i < htControls.Count; i++)
    {
        //clone control 
        Control cntrl = CloneControl((Control)htControls[i]);

        switch (templateType)
        {
            case ListItemType.Header:
                break;
            case ListItemType.Item:
                ph.Controls.Add(cntrl);
                break;
            case ListItemType.AlternatingItem:
                ph.Controls.Add(cntrl);
                ph.DataBinding += new EventHandler(Item_DataBinding);
                break;
            case ListItemType.Footer:
                break;
        }
    }
    ph.DataBinding += new EventHandler(Item_DataBinding);
    container.Controls.Add(ph);
}
public void Item_DataBinding(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    PlaceHolder ph = (PlaceHolder)sender;
    GridViewRow ri = (GridViewRow)ph.NamingContainer;
    for (int i = 0; i < htControls.Count; i++)
    {
        if (htBindPropertiesNames[i].ToString().Length > 0)
        {
            Control tmpCtrl = (Control)htControls[i];

            String item1Value = GetType(htBindExpression[i].ToString(), ri);

            //Guid value = new Guid(DataBinder.Eval(ri.DataItem, htBindExpression[i].ToString()).ToString());
            //String valueString = value.ToString();
            //item1Value = item1Value1.ToString();

            Control ctrl = ph.FindControl(tmpCtrl.ID);
            Type t = ctrl.GetType();
            System.Reflection.PropertyInfo pi = t.GetProperty(htBindPropertiesNames[i].ToString());
            if (pi != null)
            {
                pi.SetValue(ctrl, item1Value.ToString(), null);
            }
        }
    }
}

private String GetType(String ColumnName, GridViewRow row)
{
    String Result = "";
    clsSearch obj = new clsSearch();
    // i have set up the table name static as now we require to make search working for macintosh project only.
    // as per rakesh sir directed.
    Int32 Type = obj.GetNumberForDataTypeofColumn("tblProperty", ColumnName);
    switch (Type)
    {
        case 1:
            DateTime dtvalue = (DateTime)DataBinder.Eval(row.DataItem, ColumnName);
            Result = dtvalue.ToString();
            break;
        case 2:
            String svalue = (String)DataBinder.Eval(row.DataItem, ColumnName);
            Result = svalue;
            break;
        case 3:

            break;
        case 4:
            Int32 ivalue = (Int32)DataBinder.Eval(row.DataItem, ColumnName);
            Result = ivalue.ToString();
            break;
        case 5:
            Guid gvalue = (Guid)DataBinder.Eval(row.DataItem, ColumnName);
            Result = gvalue.ToString();
            break;
    }

    return Result;
}

private Control CloneControl(System.Web.UI.Control src_ctl)
{
    Type t = src_ctl.GetType();
    Object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
    Control dst_ctl = (Control)obj;
    PropertyDescriptorCollection src_pdc = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(src_ctl);
    PropertyDescriptorCollection dst_pdc = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(dst_ctl);

    for (int i = 0; i < src_pdc.Count; i++)
    {
        if (src_pdc[i].Attributes.Contains(DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute.Content))
        {
            object collection_val = src_pdc[i].GetValue(src_ctl);
            if ((collection_val is IList) == true)
            {
                foreach (object child in (IList)collection_val)
                {
                    Control new_child = CloneControl(child as Control);
                    object dst_collection_val = dst_pdc[i].GetValue(dst_ctl);
                    ((IList)dst_collection_val).Add(new_child);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            dst_pdc[src_pdc[i].Name].SetValue(dst_ctl, src_pdc[i].GetValue(src_ctl));
        }
    }

    return dst_ctl;

}
```

}

and use it like the below:

```
TemplateField t = new TemplateField();
            DynamicTemplate mt = new DynamicTemplate(ListItemType.Item);

            mt.TableName = TableName;
            if (IsEditButtonVisible == 1)
            {
                Image ibtnEdit = new Image();
                ibtnEdit.ID = "btnEdit";
                ibtnEdit.CssClass = "EditButton";
                ibtnEdit.ImageUrl = EditButtonImageSrc;
                ibtnEdit.Style.Add("cursor", "pointer");
                ibtnEdit.ToolTip = "View Details";
                mt.AddControl(ibtnEdit, "AlternateText", "Id");
            }
            if (IsDeleteButtonVisible == 1)
            {
                Image ibtnDelete = new Image();
                ibtnDelete.ID = "ibtnDelete";
                ibtnDelete.CssClass = "DeleteButton";
                ibtnDelete.ImageUrl = DeleteButtonImageSrc;
                mt.AddControl(ibtnDelete, "AlternateText", "Id");
            }
            t.ItemTemplate = mt;
            t.HeaderText = "Activity";
            t.HeaderStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
            GridView1.Columns.Add(t);
        }
        GridView1.DataSource = dtOutPutResult;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

I am adding buttons in the same you can do it for checkbox