# Add checkboxes to a CheckBoxField column

Tags: c#, asp.net

I created a CheckBoxField and added it to my GridView, I would like to know how I can add a checkbox to each row of the new column:

```cs
CheckBoxField field = new CheckBoxField();
field.HeaderText = "Export ?";
gv.Columns.Add(field);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to add checkbox column to gridview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075044/how-to-add-checkbox-column-to-gridview)

Answer (score 0):

I've done similar with a DataGridView (WinForms). This code should help you get a good bit on the way:

```
            // add new checkbox to source
            var checkBoxColumn = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
            checkBoxColumn.HeaderText = "Move";
            checkBoxColumn.Name = "chkMove";

            // add new binding
            dgCheckBoxes.Columns.Insert(0, checkBoxColumn);

            // set values
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgCheckBoxes.Rows)
            {
                if (true)
                {
                    row.Cells["chkMove"].Value = true;
                }
                else
                {                        
                    row.Cells["chkMove"].Value = false;
                }
            }
```

For a WebForms solution, you should be able to use this Demo from Microsoft: [Adding a GridView Column of Checkboxes](https://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/data-access/enhancing-the-gridview/adding-a-gridview-column-of-checkboxes-cs)

Comment: I couldn't find the class DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn, I tried to add "using System.Windows.Forms" to my code but doesn't work, maybe it's because I'm working with webform and not mvc?

Comment: Ah, my code is from WinForm, not Web/MVC. I have just done something similar in Web though. Stand by and I will edit my answer.

Comment: @Kikus, Unfortunately, I've done it with Telerik, so I don't think it will be much help for you.